# Kivy Image Buttons Are Shaped Like... Lemons?

Tags: kivy

I'm trying build a GUI in python with an array of buttons and some circular menu items on the right. I made a some png files for the menu items, but when I add them as buttons into the code, it shows them kind of like two lemons on top of each other rotated 90˚. A bit like this: [Lemon Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWiWD.png)

These are the icons that I made:

[Circular Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoJ5W.png)

Here is the code I have right now.

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

buttonSize = (0.3, 0.2)

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):

        layout = FloatLayout()

        button1 = Button(
            text='1st Function', 
            size_hint=buttonSize,
            pos_hint={'x':.05, 'y':.75}
        )
        
        button2 = Button(
            text='2nd Function',
            size_hint=buttonSize,
            pos_hint={'x':.4, 'y':.75}
        )

        button3 = Button(
            text='3rd Function',
            size_hint=buttonSize,
            pos_hint={'x':.05, 'y':.475}
        )

        button4 = Button(
            text='4th Function',
            size_hint=buttonSize,
            pos_hint={'x':0.4, 'y':0.475}
        )

        button5 = Button(
            text='5th Function',
            size_hint=buttonSize,
            pos_hint={'x':.05, 'y':.2}
        )

        button6 = Button(
            text='6th Function',
            size_hint=buttonSize,
            pos_hint={'x':0.4, 'y':0.2}
        )

        menuButton = Button(
            background_normal='Circular Button.png',
            background_down='Circular Button Down.png',
            size_hint=(0.125, 0.15),
            pos_hint={'x':0.8, 'y':0.8}
        )

        patientButton = Button(
            background_normal='Patient Button.png',
            background_down='Patient Button Down.png',
            size_hint=(0.125, 0.15),
            pos_hint={'x':0.8, 'y':0.5}
        )

        layout.add_widget(button1)
        layout.add_widget(button2)
        layout.add_widget(button3)
        layout.add_widget(button4)
        layout.add_widget(button5)
        layout.add_widget(button6)
        layout.add_widget(menuButton)
        layout.add_widget(patientButton)

        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

How do I get the icons to show normal circles instead of these monstrosities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the (lack of) border attribute.
Fix it by setting borders to 0 as follows:

```python
menuButton = Button(
    background_normal='Circular Button.png',
    background_down='Circular Button Down.png',
    size_hint=(0.1, 0.1),
    pos_hint={'x':0.8, 'y':0.8},
    border=(0, 0, 0, 0)
)

patientButton = Button(
    background_normal='Patient Button.png',
    background_down='Patient Button Down.png',
    size_hint=(0.2, 0.2),
    pos_hint={'x':0.8, 'y':0.5},
    border=(0, 0, 0, 0)
)
```

Result (images are not perfectly square and I set second one to twice the size hint, this is just for testing):

[image]